# Fast way to validate URL in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I use this function to validate URLs in google apps:

```
function url_exists(url) {
  var retValue = false;

  try {
    var safeurl=url.replace(/[{}]/g,"");
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(safeurl);
    if(response.getResponseCode() == 200) {  
      retValue = true;
    }
  } catch (err) {
    retValue = false;
  }
  return retValue;
}
```

I have it tied to a 'validate' custom menu option in a spreadsheet so I can manually run it on a range whenever I need it. The function works great with just a few URLs, but becomes very slow if I run it for more than 50. I'm guessing that UrlFetchApp.fetch() may be downloading the file even though I only need to know that it exists.

How can I improve efficiency/speed of this function?

Answer (score 3):

To know if a web site exist you have to contact the server. To save bandwidth and hence speed-up the process, you would normally query for the HTTP HEAD only. 
`fetch(url, params)` has parameters - in particular the `method` option which should be set at "head" instead of "get". 
Google documentation says: "*the HTTP method for the request: 'post', 'get', 'put', 'delete', etc. The default is 'get'.*"

I did a test, and with "head" the fetch is not working. So it would seems Google did not implemented the feature.

Comment: There has been a feature request for `UrlFetchApp` calls with method=HEAD since 2014. The issue was assigned to someone in 2017. If we're lucky, the feature will be implemented by 2020. :-) https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36762291

Comment: It is 2020 and this is still a pending feature request.